# does queue create a copy?

Tags: c++, stl

If I push an existing object into a queue:

```
struct Node {int x; int y;};
std::vector<Node> vec;
vec.push_back(Node(1, 3));

std::queue<Node> q;
q.push(vec[0]);
```

At the last line, does `q` store the **address** (pointer or reference, whatever except the object itself) **of `vec[0]`**, or does it copy **the whole `Node` object** into `q`?

Comment: Find out yourself: Set a breakpoint in the copy-constructor or read the documentation (cppreference.com comes to mind).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will get copied as you assign an rvalue reference. It will get moved if you assign an lvalue reference. (temporary object).

To check, use copy constructor / operator and move constructor / operator overloading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

struct Node {
    int x;
    int y;

    Node(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Node(Node const & original) : x(original.x), y(original.y)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Node(Node const && original) : x(original.x), y(original.y)
    {
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Node & operator=(Node const & original) {
        std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;
        if(this != &original) {
            x = original.x;
            y = original.y;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Node & operator=(Node const && original) {
        std::cout << "move operator" << std::endl;
        if(this != &original) {
            x = original.x;
            y = original.y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {

    std::vector<Node> v;

    Node n(1,3);        // constructor
    Node m(3, 4);       // constructor

    m = n;              // assignment operator
    n = Node(2, 3);     // constructor + move operator

    v.push_back({1,2});     // constructor + move constructor
    v.push_back(n);         // copy constructor

    std::queue<Node> q;
    q.push(v[0]);           // copy constructor

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I learned a lot. Thanks. I did't know there were so many different constructor and operators.

Comment: Most of them are implicit so you won't have to implement them except if you do dynamic allocation. Move constructors and operators are explicit, so you'll have to implement them otherwise their copy version is used.

Comment: By the way, you can also delete them if you want to inhibit copy construction for example use: Node(Node const & original) = delete;

Comment: What is = delete? never seen that. Can I "=delete" any function to make it disappear?

Comment: no, delete will instruct the compiler to not create an implicit version of copy constructor / operator or destructor. You can't just "delete" a function to make it disappear ;)

Answer (score 5):

It does create a copy. In fact, you can always find out where a copy or move occurs by overwriting the copy or move constructors:

```
class Node 
{
public:
    Node(int x, int y) { std::cout << "Create node" << std::endl; }
    Node(const Node&) { std::cout << "Copy node" << std::endl; }
    Node(Node&&) { std::cout << "Move node" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Node() = default;
};
```

For your program this prints

```
Create node
Move node
Copy node
```

Since

```
std::vector<Node> vec;
vec.push_back(Node(1, 3));  // Creates a temporary node and moves it into the vector.

std::queue<Node> q;
q.push(vec[0]);             // Copys the node.
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/push/) the signatures of push function in queue are:
`std::queue::push(const value_type& val)`
`std::queue::push(value_type&& val)`

So it is basically gets copied to the queue, which can be verified by:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main() {
    int iarray[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    std::queue<int> q;
    q.push(iarray[2]);
    std::cout << q.front();
    iarray[2] = 4;
    std::cout << q.front();
    return 0;
}
```

---

To clarify,

This is what happens:

the line `q.push(iarray[2]);` calls `void push (const value_type& val)`
from the queue class.

The definition of `void push (const value_type& val)` is:

```
void push(const value_type& _Val) {
    c.push_back(_Val);
}
```

Where `c` is a protected instance of the `_Container` class
The line `c.push_back(_Val)` actually calls the copy constructor of the `_Val` object