# Solving Memory Leaks from Parsing and Factory Pattern in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, factory-pattern

I'm trying to parse arguments from the command line when I run an executable. The arguments can either be single-digit numbers or operators("+", "-", "*", "/", and "**" for exponent). I call a function in my Factory to parse and create objects for each type of argument: `Base* parse(char** argv, int argc)`.

I'm using a queue of char pointers and a stack of char pointers, where the queue ends up being a postfix notation of the arguments, and then this queue is used to create Base objects that are written into a queue of Base pointers.

I'm getting a segfault, and valgrind is telling me that I'm not freeing memory, but I don't know what to free in this context. I also don't fully know if my method that I outlined above works. Any input helps!

```
class BaseFactory {
public:
    Base* parse(char** input, int length) {
        queue<char*> charQueue;
        stack<char*> charStack;
        string charString;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            charString = static_cast<string>(input[i]);
            if(isdigit(charString.at(0))) {
                charQueue.push(input[i]);
            } else if((charString == "+") || (charString == "-") ||
                      (charString == "*") || (charString == "/") ||
                      (charString == "**")) {
                while(!charStack.empty()) {
                    charQueue.push(charStack.top());
                    charStack.pop();
                }
                charStack.push(input[i]);
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if(!charStack.empty()) {
            charQueue.push(charStack.top());
            charStack.pop();
        }
        queue<Base*> secondQueue;
        Base* base1;
        Base* base2;
        Base* base3;
        while(!charQueue.empty()) {
            charString == static_cast<string>(charQueue.front());
            if(charString == "+") {
                base2 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base3 = secondQueue.front(); // segfault here?
                secondQueue.pop();
                base1 = new Add(base2, base3);
                secondQueue.push(base1);
                charQueue.pop();
            } else if(charString == "-") {
                base2 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base3 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base1 = new Sub(base2, base3);
                secondQueue.push(base1);
                charQueue.pop();
            } else if(charString == "*") {
                base2 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base3 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base1 = new Mult(base2, base3);
                secondQueue.push(base1);
                charQueue.pop();
            }

            else if(charString == "/") {
                base2 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base3 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base1 = new Div(base2, base3);
                secondQueue.push(base1);
                charQueue.pop();
            } else if(charString == "**") {
                base2 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base3 = secondQueue.front();
                secondQueue.pop();
                base1 = new Pow(base2, base3);
                secondQueue.push(base1);
                charQueue.pop();
            } else {
                double temp;
                temp = stod(charString);
                base1 = new Op(temp);
                charQueue.pop();
                secondQueue.push(base1);
            }
        }

        return secondQueue.front();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your whole code? Use ``` ``` around to format it nicely

Comment: if parse returns a Base*, where does the memory of your Base live?

Comment: You solve memory leaks by not using `new`. This is 2021, learn to use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Added the code!

Comment: Please add a [mre] where you use your class. It'll be super-easy to help then.

Comment: At what point of your development did your program not work successfully?  If you don't know that, then this is why you shouldn't develop a whole lot of code like this without incrementally testing it.  You could have written, for example, just the test for `*` and make sure no memory leaks exist.  Then add another operator, and test that, etc.

Comment: You allocate some memory with  `base1 = new Add(base2, base3);` then push the instance to the queue.  It's been a while since I wrote c++ but this seems to invoke copy constructor per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889877/does-queue-create-a-copy.  I don't see any matching delete.  @Blindy gives you very good advise on how address this.  If the program crashes give us a backtrace, and if you ran valgrind share the relevant information.  And post a self-contained example so we have a chance to compile your program to debug it.